# Moderators can now exclude questions from the HNQ list – when should we use this?

Tags: discusión, faq, moderación, hnq

#### The mechanics

Hot Network Questions (HNQ) are questions shown in the bottom right sidebar featuring from other sites of the Stack Exchange network that are considered “hot” by a heuristic that takes into account recent visits, answers, and votes.

There can be issues when one of our questions becomes an HNQ because its increased exposure leads to considerably higher number of visitors – many of whom are unfamiliar with our site and our community standards.

Moderators can now remove individual questions from the Hot Network Questions list ([announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060)).

**This process is irreversible**.

After removing a question, we cannot decide that we want to allow it to go hot again.

#### How can we use this?

Having a meta discussion about whether a specific question should be removed from the HNQs is not a good idea, because by the time the discussion has reached any sort of consensus, the potential damage has probably already been done.

So, we moderators have to decide on relatively quickly and on a case-by-case basis whether a question should be removed.

**If you feel that any question should not be an HNQ, please flag it for moderator attention and elaborate why.**

This naturally makes the most sense for questions that are already HNQs (which you can now [see in the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641/255554)), but if you think it is likely that a question will become an HNQ, but shouldn’t, feel free to flag it.

Please do not do this for questions that you consider in need of editing, cleaning up, closing, or similar.

Instead perform or suggest the respective edits, flag the problematic comments or answers for deletion, or flag for closure.

#### What questions should not be HNQs?

Occasionally, we will remove a question from the HNQs, when there is a serious problem, and given their individual nature, some of these problems are unforeseeable.

However, we as a community can agree that we do not want certain types of question to be HNQs and try to remove them as quickly as possible.

Therefore I am asking:

**Are there any categories of questions that we *generally* do not want to be HNQs?**

If you think so, please suggest categories in the answers:

- Suggest one category per answer.
- Provide a rationale why such questions being HNQs is a problem.
- Do not suggest categories of questions that should be closed or can be salvaged with an edit.
- Do not post a blanket answer that no categories should be excluded. It will be very difficult to interpret the community consensus if such an answer and answers suggesting a category receive positive scores.
  Also, you do not know what possible good answers (i.e. specifying a category you didn't think of) may come afterwards.
  The way to decide that no categories should be excluded is by not having any well scoring answers suggesting a category to be excluded.
- Remember that at the end of the day we have to decide on a case-by-case basis, by answering the question: "Do we have this kind of problem on our site?"  Therefore a good rationale is more important than precisely defining the category.
- Use votes to indicate agreement or disagreement with proposed categories.

Comment: Coincido con Walen. El otro día alguien en Workplace publicó una pregunta tipo "He reportado a mi jefe por hacer algo ilegal y ahora me está haciendo la vida imposible" y el OP publicaba con sus datos (su nombre de usuario parecía ser su nombre y apellido real, lo que puede ser un problema serio en los stack como Workplace, Legal, etc.). No solemos tener muchas preguntas en las HNQ y de hecho creo que no entran si están escritas en español. Dicho esto, la discusión merece tenerse, e incluso ampliarse a otras preguntas no en las HNQ que pudiesen tener problemas similares.

Comment: I only found this site via HNQ when I was subscribed to one of the other sites so I think the maximum exposure is to be sought to attract other possible users.

Comment: @Diego no se me ocurre motivo alguno ahora mismo para excluir preguntas nuestras de las HNQ. Si una pregunta lo hace es porque 1) está redactada en su mayor parte en inglés, 2) ha atraído atención y está siendo votada y 3) ha recibido al menos una respuesta que ha sido bien votada. Nos cuesta trabajo cumplir estos tres requisitos, y cuando lo conseguimos se agradecen las visitas que nos aporta. Si queremos excluir una pregunta de las HNQ será porque no cumpla las reglas del sitio, y en ese caso lo que hay que hacer es cerrarla, lo que (creo) excluye la pregunta automáticamente de las HNQ.

Comment: @Charlie sí, efectivamente uno de los requisitos para que una pregunta entre en el HNQ es que no esté cerrada. Más en general, publiqué esta pregunta-plantilla pues nos la sugirieron a los moderadores en general. Estoy de acuerdo con todos en que _no_ entrar en el HNQ no es nuestro objetivo ahora, pero quede aquí el debate por si algún día encontramos algún patrón de preguntas que no nos gusta que representen a nuestro sitio.

Comment: If I should put this in an answer, please tell me.  The instructions were too complicated for me so I am copping out and writing a comment. // I learned some time ago at SE Academia that if you write a serious question with a title that mentions anything about scanty women's clothing, you will land on the HNQ list and get unproductive drive-by answers and comments.  So, if any question or title will bring UNWANTED attention, for whatever reason, that would be a question that the moderators should make HNQ-immune. // When the US Supreme Court looked into pornography, they found that they...

Comment: ... couldn't *define* it.  They said that people know it when they see it.  Material that should not be on HNQ is a bit like that.

Comment: @aparente haha I loved the last part, good one! Yes, I think we all agreed here that for Spanish.SE it doesn't look like we are going to need much of this (and when we do, we'll see it :P)